# Do Pals need to be released in order for their passive abilities to be in effect?

Tags: palworld

Say I have a Pal with both Logging Foreman and Mine Foreman. Do I need to have to released and following me around to get the bonus logging/mining efficiency, or is simply having the Pal in my party enough for the passive to be active?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some **science!** For each of the below scenarios, I recorded the highest hit I observed, not the average, as there's a good bit of variance.

Short answer is -- you don't need the pal out; having them on you is good enough.

- No Pals in Party: **~158** / hit with a metal axe
- Gumoss in party: **~178** / hit with a metal axe
- Logging Foreman Pal in party: **~206** / hit with a metal axe
- Lucky Logging Foreman Gumoss in party: **~222** / hit with a metal axe